# rms width calculation

Tags: stochastic-processes, random

I have a Equation with following form:
$$v(t)=e^{-( t/T_0 )^2}\sum_{n=-N}^{n=N}C_nCos(n\Omega t)$$
where $C_n $ is uniform random variable that take two integer 1 or -1 ,and $\Omega ,T_0, N $ are Constant, I want to calculate of rms width of this random process, and rms defined with following relation:
$$T_\sigma=[<T^2>-<T>^2]^{1/2} $$
and 
$$<T^2>= {\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}t^n|v(t)|^2dt  \over\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|v(t)|^2dt} $$

Please Help me!